# Google Maps - requests to reviews places I've never visited

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps insists on asking me to review places that I've never visited.  I've tried both "Dismiss" and "I haven't been here"" but they keep coming back.  It's very frustrating especially when the places I have visited and I do want to review get lost in the seemingly endless list of places I've perhaps gone past but never visited.